Google Play Store publishing without 'Play App Signing'
I may be having a senior moment, but I'm pretty sure something has changed since I last published a new app on Google Play.
I am building the new app in Android Studio as I have always done. As I have kept AS up to date I am now using Koala which has some obvious changes, but I am now wondering if something has changed in terms of creating APKs and the associated signing.
I can sign my app no problem and it build and runs on the emulator and on a couple of my test devices.
I am now ready to publish to Google Play for internal testing.
I publish APKs (rather than app bundles) out of choice as I prefer t manage my own keys rather than using 'Play App Signing'.
Now, when I try to upload the APK to a new Internal Testing release on the Google Play Console, there is a message saying I have to ' provide a signing key or generate one using Play app signing'.
I don't remember having to do this before, but it is quite a while since I have published a new app. (Though I have been publishing updates to my existing apps throughout).
It looks like I may have to create a .pem key from my existing .jks keystore files... or am I misunderstanding something?
Hunting around the Google Developer pages it talks about using keytool which I do not have on my machine - I have searched the bin folders in the JRE bundled with AS but cannot find it.
I am at a loss.
Searching the open web everything I can find points to using Google App Signing.
(I know there are arguments for using Google App Signing, but I want to know how to publish my app with my own control f the signing keys as I always have done. At least for now.)
What am I missing?
It looks like it should still be possible to sign without using Google App Signing - see the below screenshots from the Google Play Developer Console:


I know that Google App Signing is mandatory for App Bundle distribution, but I thought it was optional for APK distribution.

I dont remember exactly when but app signing became mandatory somewhat recently

@tyczj I've just added a couple of screenshots that imply you still have the option of not using Google managed signing.

Yeah you can certainly create your own key that you upload to google but you still need to let google manage it similar to just having google create a key

Found the reference to it finally in the Android Dev pages.. grrrr. Oh well.... and it changed not actually that recently either. Over three years ago!

Finally found it...
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing#:~:text=For%20Google%20Play%20Store%2C%20all%20apps%20created,are%20required%20to%20use%20Play%20App%20Signing.
So, as of August 2021 all new apps distributed on the Google Play Store must use Google App Signing.
Oh well, that's that, then.
